# getting nil when try to save object to a CloudKit record

Tags: swift, cloudkit

Im trying to save an object to a CloudKit record to
[my CloudKit model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONKxx.png)

```
func savePlaceToCloud (id: Int, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, title: String, additionalInfo: String) {
    let place = CKRecord(recordType: "Place")
    place.setValue(id, forKey: "id")
    place.setValue(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    place.setValue(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
    place.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
    place.setValue(additionalInfo, forKey: "additionalInfo")
    print(place)

    publicDB.saveRecord(place, completionHandler: { (record, error) -> Void in
        print(record)
        NSLog("saved to iCloud")
    })
}
```

[here is a console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAwqC.png)

Comment: where do you get the nill? Plus what is `publicDB` ?

Comment: im getting nil inside publicDB.saveRecord closure
publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase - a cloudKit use private and public databases to separate private and public user data

Comment: and what do you get if you print the error there?

Comment: can't you check if the error is nil or not? if it is nil that means it is saved. Otherwise, the data hasn't been saved. Plus, what is `container`? I need to have a working code in order to debug your problem

Comment: printing error returns 
Optional(<CKError 0x787733e0: "Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "This request requires an authenticated account"; Retry after 3.0 seconds>)

Comment: container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up here searching for "cloudkit This request requires an authenticated account" on google. The problem for me was that I wasn't signed in to iCloud inside the simulator.